# To use SQLite with Datasnap

Tags: sqlite, delphi, datasnap

Is it ok to use SQLite as a backend database in Datasnap ? Will there be a danger of database locking since SQLite is filebased or will the datasnap server provide the necessary backbone for this not to happen ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Datasnap, but with working directly with SQLite ([...](https://github.com/stijnsanders/TSQLite)) I know SQLite is able to use one file/database from several processes and keep track of lock using mutexes. (See more about sqlite's mutex functions [here](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/mutex_alloc.html)) How they work exactly depends on which compile settings were used when building sqlite3.dll. I've been using the precompiled binaries from the website without any problem.